# how to use the display value of the Foxpro combobox

Tags: combobox, foxpro

I have a combo box that I would like it to show a

`category name ("Cat1" , "Cat2"...)`

But when clicked or just displayed I would like to get the ID of this category. Any idea how to do this in Foxpro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To populate your combobox:

```
Thisform.Combo1.AddItem("Cat1")
Thisform.Combo1.AddItem("Cat2")
```

You may use rowsource to add the entire item list into the combobox.

Get the selected value of combobox:

```
Thisform.Combo1.DisplayValue
```

- Please [refer to this article](http://www.universalthread.com/ViewPageArticle.aspx?ID=590)

Answer (score 1):

Create a cursor that contains what you want to display in the first column and the ID in the second. Then, set up the combo like this:

```
RowSourceType = 2-Alias
RowSource = <your cursor name>
BoundColumn = 2
BoundTo = .T. && so you can have a numeric controlsource
```

Tamar

Comment: Thanks a lot, how about bi-directional mapping ? from a table where the id is stored, i would like to display the category name ? i appreciate your help

Comment: Set the combo's ControlSource to the field containing the ID.